# Modern Swing deployments and JVM appointments

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jvm, java-web-start

Java 8/Groovy 2.4.3/2015 A.D. here. I have a need to write a Swing app that will be installed on desktop/laptops, and I'm wondering what modern Swing app dev looks like with regards to:

- **Installers & auto-updaters** - That is, utilities (perhaps including a wizard) for *properly* installing the Swing app (executable JAR) on any desktop (Windows, Mac, Linux), as well as handling autoupdates when they're available
- **Combating native JREs** - I'd like to ship the JAR with its own JVM (like what Eclipse does) and force the JAR to use that JVM on start; that way I'm not struggling to compete with whatever the default JVM version the user/OS has already installed on the machine

**I should note:** Web start is *not* an option here because end users will very likely be in remote areas that have no network connection.

So I ask:

- Any particular (modern) techniques I can leverage for deployment/installation and auto-updating?
- What trick(s) is Eclipse using to force Eclipse to use the JVM it ships with?

Comment: Write the updater using a `TimerTask`, write the Installer yourself (You shouldn't need one at all -> What would you do with it? Mac users hate installers). Command line argument to use your own JRE.

Comment: Thanks @Zizouz212 (+1) - with regards to the `TimerTask`, how might this work? If the `TimerTask` is a part of the JAR itself (say, `myapp.jar`), how would it update...itself?!? It almost seems like I need **two (2)** executables: the app itself (again, `myapp.jar`) an then a `myapp-updater.jar`) that runs this `TimerTask` and updates the main JAR...thoughts?

Comment: Well, the decision to update generally lies with the user, so a simple dialog with a link to a download location would probably be enough (it's a start at least). The `TimerTask` can schedule events for you (make a method be called once a week for example). That method can check if a newer version is available, and alert the user.

Comment: The `TimerTask` is just a class in `java.util`. You can keep it within your main application.

Comment: Thanks again, but I feel like you're missing the point of my question w.r.t this auto-updating `TimerTask`. If the app installs to, say, `/home/myuser/myapp/myapp.jar`, and this timer task is part of that main JAR, how would it: (1) fetch a new `myapp.jar` from a server and install it to the same place where a JAR of the same name is already executing, and (2) shutdown the current `myapp.jar` and then start the new one, and (3) delete the old one (that is no longer running)?

Comment: So you want the existing application to foster that auto-update?

Comment: Eclipse does not ship with a JVM. A RCP based on Eclipse can include a JVM, the RCP launcher executable deals with that.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 (+1) - whats an RCP?

Comment: RCP is a Rich Client Program, a package of Eclipse plugins (Eclipse itself is an RCP). This is not usable for Swing as Eclipse uses SWT or JavaFX.

Comment: There are a number of installers available and native executable wrappers, we use exe4j and bundle the JRE with our app, directing the exe4j to execute or bundle. We wrote our own updater which uses "patch" style process, basically checking MD5's of the various files and choosing which ones need to be updated.  The patching process also generates a patch from version a to version b, where only the files which have actually changed are included.  This is all managed through zip files so it's relatively easy to manage

Comment: *"end users will very likely be in remote areas that have no network connection."*  uh-huh.. so how is *"handling autoupdates when they're available"* supposed to work?  How do the users even know about or receive the updates?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - they will not **always** be in these remote areas

Comment: Also, I should mention this because I definitely feel a lot of social justice groupthink setting on here, end users will be employees who have already signed agreements consenting to keeping their systems up to date at all times. So this isn't some shady "*We're going to force these updates on you even if you don't want us to*" type of situation here.

Comment: *"..they will not **always** be in these remote areas.."*  That makes it easy then.  Deploy using JWS.  Take programmatic control of updates.  When [`!BasicService.isOffline()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#isOffline--), use the [`DownloadService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html?javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) to update the app..

Answer (score 1):

Currently we used [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packager.htm) which despite the name works just "fine" for Swing apps. Its buggy, limited and needs a Mac to build a Mac distribution and a Windows machine to build a Windows distribution but it does bundle the JRE which is something.

Since we use it in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/)'s desktop builds its not a big problem as we have Mac, Windows and Linux machines in the cloud.

Notice that this will do nothing for auto update but since modern apps are shipped thru stores (both Windows and Mac stores) they take care of the update for you.